# How can I import just data *and indexes* into Oracle 11?

Tags: import, indexing, oracle11g

I am importing into an Oracle 11g database using [the original `imp` tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/original_import.htm). Usually I do this with the parameter `DATA_ONLY=y` because I am only concerned with data-related errors.

However, I am now investigating some indexing-related issues, so I want to import indexes as well as data, but no other metadata. I've looked at `imp help=y` and the documentation linked above, but I can't figure out what combination of options, or what sequence of `imp` calls, would achieve this.

Any ideas? (Parameters specific to 11g answers are fine as long as they would work on a 10g dmp file too.)

Comment: Do you mean the indexes don't exist and you need to create them, or they exist but aren't being used - which would maybe be because stats haven't been gathered since the import?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am creating a near-clone of the original database from scratch, so the indexes don't exist - your answer addresses my needs exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to build the indexes from a dump file (from `exp`; not sure why you aren't using data pump and `expdp`/`impdp` if you're on 11g, but hopefully you're moving data from 9i or something) is with the [`INDEXFILE` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/original_import.htm#autoId40).

Use that to create a `.sql` file with all the index DDL. (It has all the table DDL too, but commented out). You can then make changes if you need to. Then run it as a normal script from SQL*Plus, and it will execute the DDL and build all the indexes. There isn't an `imp` call to only build the indexes, you need to do it in those two steps.

It won't update or recreate any indexes you already have, so if an index definition has changed then it will have effect - it will just complain that the index already exists. You can drop existing indexes before running the script if that's the case.

Generally you'd run the `INDEXFILE` call as a separate step after the `DATA_ONLY` call, because it's usually faster to build the indexes when all the data is present than it is to import the data with the indexes in place - because of the overhead of updating the indexes for each row of data. So, `imp DATA_ONLY=y`, then `imp INDEXFILE=ind.sql`, then `sqlplus user/pass < ind.sql`.